# regular expression to use in PHP for removing particular text in brackets from a text string

Tags: php, regex

Can't figure this one out...
I need a regular expression to use in PHP for removing particular text from a text string...

My text strings are like this:
"The product we're talking about [Art.0430000] is a good product"
"The product we're talking about [Art.0430001] is a good product"
"The product we're talking about [Art.7852000] is a good product"

I need to remove [Art.0430000], [Art.0430001], [Art.7852000] from the strings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you also want to compress the white space left over (2 spaces to 1 space);

```
$pattern = '/\[Art\.[0-9]+\]\s*/';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, "", $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression should be:

```
\[Art\.[0-9]+\]
```

(In words: The literal string "[Art.", followed by one or more numerals in the range 0-9, followed by the literal string "]".)

In PHP:

```
$pattern = '/\[Art\.[0-9]+\]/';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, "", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it should work:

```
preg_replace_all("/\[Art(^\]+)\]/", "", $string);
```

Answer (score -1):

$pattern = "#\[Art\.([o-9])+\]#";
str_replace($pattern,"",$str);